# Laravel - PDO - UPDATING

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, pdo

Alright , a PDO code when I run in my localhost works perfect , but when I 
run in my host doesnt work and gives me an error which is

QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 (SQL: UPDATE roles SET member_id=76446,member_role=5613 WHERE member_id=76446)

the code is

```
if (!empty($member->id)) {



        $new_id = $member->id;

        $new_p = $member->p_id;

        $sql = "UPDATE roles SET member_id=$new_id,member_role=$new_p WHERE member_id=$new_id";

        $member = DB::select($sql);

        Session::flash('sm', 'Thank you! You have edited the Profile successfully!');

    }
```

I appreciate help !

Comment: connection.php is a laravel system .

Comment: It's all correct , If it wasn't correct the site wasn't connected to the database and wasn't working.

Comment: Does Laravel really use a `select()` method for `UPDATE/INSERT` queries?  Seems like [this the preferred, documented method](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)

Comment: Yes, but you have the question tagged Laravel, which has all its own internal conventions for using PDO. The `DB::select()` is _not_ PDO in and of itself. That is a Laravel function.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel got built in [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries)
so your code should look like -

```
if (!empty($member->id)) {

        $new_id = $member->id;

        $new_p = $member->p_id;

        DB::table('roles')->where('member_id', $new_id)->update(['member_role' => $new_p]);

        Session::flash('sm', 'Thank you! You have edited the Profile successfully!');

    }
```

I removed the `member_id=$new_id` as you already check this part in the `where` clause